# Create HttpMessageHandler on .NET Core with possibility to make requests to myself

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a nightly job on .NET Core 2.1 app to make request to https://server/api/values
This request should be done from server to server itself (kind of TestServer behaviour), **without** actual network activity or authorization policy applied.

Is there way to do it? I was using HttpServer as HttpMessageHandler on full .NET, but it's not the case with .NET Core.

EDIT:
Here is a sample app, which fails on Autoruns service. 
https://github.com/Lonli-Lokli/middleware_example

Comment: Does the server call itself? The code appears to setup an HttpClient so you can call a controller within the same service?

Comment: Yep, I should call to myself (with relative or absolute url). I cannot call direct controller or service because actual url comes from outside. It's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you’re looking for is the HttpClientFactory.. But, you’ll probably need to provide more details (code example of what you have tried) if you want a more complete answer

Comment: I've added link to sample repo